# Pyttsx Voice Gender

Tags: python, python-2.7, voice, pyttsx

Good afternoon, I'm learning and using pyttsx for speech, the thing is that I want to use it as a "female" voice but I can not do it using this code:

```
import pyttsx as pt
from pyttsx import voice
engine = pt.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
#engine.setProperty('gender', 'female') # also does not work
engine.setProperty('female', voice.Voice.gender) #not even
engine.setProperty('female', voice.gender) #does not work
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[4].id)
engine.say("Hello World")
engine.runAndWait()


class Voice(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name=None, languages=[], gender=None, age=None):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.languages = languages
        self.gender = gender
        self.age = age
```

Answer (score 5):

I used the following code to iterate through the voices to find the female voice

```
import pyttsx
engine = pyttsx.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
for voice in voices:
   engine.setProperty('voice', voice.id)
   print voice.id
   engine.say('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.')
engine.runAndWait()
```

On my Windows 10 machine the female voice was HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\TTS_MS_EN-US_ZIRA_11.0

So I changed my code to look like this

```
import pyttsx
engine = pyttsx.init()
engine.setProperty('voice', 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\TTS_MS_EN-US_ZIRA_11.0')
engine.say('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.')
engine.runAndWait()
```

Answer (score 5):

if you use linux/espeak...

change the code here `engine.setProperty('voice', 'english+f1')`

you can change the voice  by adding f1 until f4

Answer (score 3):

This is a simpler solution:

```
engine = pyttsx.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sound=getProperty ('voices'); engine.setProperty('voice','sound [1].id')`
This will definitely work. 0 for male and 1 for female.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check whether your computer has other narrator options or not for that go to control panel -> Ease of Access center -> Narrator options
there will be option how many narrators you have.
other option go to windows search for narrator.
if you don't have other narrator that you have written in code, default narrator will work only.

Answer (score 0):

I use this helper function, that iterates over the voices. If a voice for a specific language and gender exists, it will change to this voice otherwise an exception will be raised.

```
# language  : en_US, de_DE, ...
# gender    : VoiceGenderFemale, VoiceGenderMale
def change_voice(engine, language, gender='VoiceGenderFemale'):
    for voice in engine.getProperty('voices'):
        if language in voice.languages and gender == voice.gender:
            engine.setProperty('voice', voice.id)
            return True

    raise RuntimeError("Language '{}' for gender '{}' not found".format(language, gender))
```

And finally it will be used like this:

```
engine = pt.init()
change_voice(engine, "en_US", "VoiceGenderFemale")
engine.say("Hello World")
engine.runAndWait()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import pyttsx as pt
from pyttsx import voice
engine = pt.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
#engine.setProperty('gender', 'female') # also does not work
#engine.setProperty('female', voice.Voice.gender) #not even
#engine.setProperty('female', voice.gender) #does not work
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)
engine.say("Hello World")
engine.runAndWait
```

Comment: Explain it please!